# altair: Text over a Heatmap in a script

Tags: python, altair

I tried to follow the Altair example of ["Text over a Heatmap"](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/layered_heatmap_text.html) but came across some problems.

My dataset consists of two indexes (`N`, `Z`) and a value column `color`.

1. I would like to set the origin at the bottom-left side.
2. How to display the heatmap with text in a script?
3. Is it possible to put labels (`N`, `Z`) in each pixel?

Below attached the part of the code.

```
def chart_altair(self):
    import altair as alt
    data = self.df.dropna().reset_index(name='color')

    # Configure common options
    base = alt.Chart(data).encode(
        alt.X('N:O'),
        alt.Y('Z:O'),
    )

    # Configure heatmap
    heatmap = base.mark_rect().encode(
        color=alt.Color(
            'color:Q',
            scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis'),
            legend=alt.Legend()
        )
    )

    text = base.mark_text(baseline='middle').encode(
        text='color:Q'
    )
```

I pasted below a few rows of my dataset which consists of two indexses `Z`, `N`, and a value column `color` (represents actually a atomic mass table). The "heatmap" should be similar to the chart of nuclei, with the neutron number increase to the right x-axis, and the proton number increases upwards in the y-axis. However, the proton number increases in the opposite direction (in the negative y-axis).

```
  Z   N  color
  0   1   8.07
  1   0   7.29
  1   1  13.14
  1   2  14.95
  2   1  14.93
  1   3  24.62
  2   2   2.42
  3   3  14.09
  4   2  18.38
  2   5  26.07
  3   4  14.91
  4   3  15.77
  5   2  27.68
```

Comment: Could you paste a few rows from your data that are needed to reproduce the problem? We can't test without knowing how df looks. Generally you could use pandas to add two columns together and use for the text label, I don't know what you mean with having origin in the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I concatenate the two labels using `transform_calculate`. You could also do this by creating the label column in pandas instead.

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Compute x^2 + y^2 across a 2D grid
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(-5, 5), range(-5, 5))
z = x ** 2 + y ** 2

# Convert this grid to columnar data expected by Altair
source = pd.DataFrame({'x': x.ravel(),
                     'y': y.ravel(),
                     'z': z.ravel()})

heatmap = alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color='z:Q'
)

heatmap + heatmap.mark_text().transform_calculate(label = '"" + datum.x + datum.y').encode(
    text='label:N',
    color=alt.value('black'))
```

[image]